# QGIS 3.1.0 not opening on Mac

Tags: qgis, mac

I've seen similar questions here and I reckon this is a common problem ever since Mac OS High Sierra, but none of the solutions proposed here and elsewhere seemed to work for me. QGIS, after installed, simply won't open. The app logo shows up in the tool bar below when I click, but that's it.

I've tried opening with a right click, reinstalling multiple times (and versions), and changing the security preferences to allow apps from anywhere to be opened, but have found myself with the same results.

Also, I think it might be worth mentioning I had a different MacOS version until a couple hours ago, but when I tried installing QGIS it said I needed a newer version of the MacOS to run it, so I upgraded it to the most recent one (13 Catalina).

Comment: I have macOs with HighSierra, and i don't have any problem with any of QGIS. I installed QGIS 2.18, QGIS 3.12. and nightly version QGIS 3.13. Try to use Parallels, and use other OS for QGIS.

Comment: Felipe have you followed the steps which are presented in this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=908NyL7roFs